# React Hydration Error on WebApp on Trying to Implement a Countdown Feature

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am building a react app and added a countdown feature to it, but I keep getting a hydration error on it and I'm not sure how to fix it. I implemented this using React Hooks and it consists of 3 files: useCountdown.js, CountdownTimer.js, DateTimeDisplay.js, index.js which are shown below in the same order. Here's the code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const useCountdown = () => {
    const countDownDate = new Date("May 20, 2023 00:00:00").getTime();
    const [countDown, setCountDown] = useState(
      countDownDate - new Date().getTime()
    );
  
    useEffect(() => {
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        setCountDown(countDownDate - new Date().getTime());
      }, 1000);
  
      return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }, [countDownDate]);
  
    return getReturnValues(countDown);
  };
  
  const getReturnValues = (countDown) => {
    // calculate time left
    const days = Math.floor(countDown / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    const hours = Math.floor(
      (countDown % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60)
    );
    const minutes = Math.floor((countDown % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    const seconds = Math.floor((countDown % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
  
    return [days, hours, minutes, seconds];
  };

  export { useCountdown };
```

```
import React from 'react';
import { useCountdown } from '../hooks/useCountdown';
import DateTimeDisplay from './DateTimeDisplay';

const ExpiredNotice = () => {
    return (
      <div className="expired-notice">
        <span>It's time to CrissCross</span>
      </div>
    );
  };
  
const ShowCounter = ({ days, hours, minutes, seconds }) => {
  return (
    <div className="show-counter">
     <span className='countdown-link'>
        <DateTimeDisplay value={days} type={'Days'} isDanger={true} />
        <DateTimeDisplay value={hours} type={'Hours'} isDanger={false} />
        <DateTimeDisplay value={minutes} type={'Mins'} isDanger={false} />      
        <DateTimeDisplay value={seconds} type={'Seconds'} isDanger={false} />
        </span>
    </div>
    
  );
};
const CountdownTimer = () => {
  const [days, hours, minutes, seconds] = useCountdown();

  if (days + hours + minutes + seconds <= 0) {
    return <ExpiredNotice />;
  } else {
    return (
      <ShowCounter
        days={days}
        hours={hours}
        minutes={minutes}
        seconds={seconds}
      />
    );
  }
};

export default CountdownTimer;
```

```
import React from 'react';

const DateTimeDisplay = ({ value, type, isDanger }) => {
  return (
    <div className={isDanger ? 'countdown danger' : 'countdown'}>
      <p>{value}</p>
      <br/>
      <span>{type}</span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DateTimeDisplay;
```

```
    import React from "react";
    import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
    import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
    import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
    import CountdownTimer from 'src/components/CountdownTimer.js'

    function HomePage() {
      return(
        <Container>
        <Navbar>
        {/* <Container> */}
          <Navbar.Brand href="#home">CrissCross</Navbar.Brand>
          <Navbar.Toggle />
          <Navbar.Collapse className="justify-content-end">
            <Navbar.Text className="navtext">
              Build Your Profile
            </Navbar.Text>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        {/* </Container> */}
      </Navbar>
        <div className="position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle" style={{textAlign: "center"}}>
        <span id="title">CrissCross</span>
        <p id="subtitle">Launches In</p>
        <CountdownTimer/>
        <Button variant="outlined" id="buildbtn">Build Your Profile</Button>
        </div>

      </Container>
      );
    }

    export default HomePage
```

I honestly have no idea why this error is happening. I read the react hydration docs but couldn't understand anything from it.

Comment: `const countDownDate = new Date("May 20, 2023 00:00:00").getTime()` - does this have the same value on client and server side?

Comment: @DmitriPavlutin I changed it to the actual number value of Date("May 20, 2023 00:00:00").getTime(). Still getting the error. Any other observations that might help?